# Activation output doesn't change much by input change [Synaptic]

Tags: javascript, linux, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using the Synaptic JS library to perform machine learning. My experience is limited to a few days now so pls forgive my ignorance on the topic. Thank you.

I am using the Architect Network with 3 inputs, 6 hidden, 6 hidden, and 1 output.

My input data is normalised and has variance.

I am using a loop to go through my dataset and to calculate for each point in time the network output. The activation output shows however low<>zero variance between each time unit while the input variance is normal. See the input and output below:

> [ [ 0.363820590302, 0.3330488358480717, 0.3116651885975185 ],   [
>   **0.5172988208539779** ] ] [ [ 0.48585295937399997, 0.3334973502634277, 0.46007835102578876 ],   [ **0.5172953785026767** ] ] [ [ 0.517562951083, 0.33397529189524716, 0.498643366077466 ],   [
>   **0.5172944759870963** ] ] [ [ 0.498637746879, 0.3344243285138506, 0.47562693669139866 ],   [ 0.517294997539339 ] ] [ [ 0.526600573119, 0.33492075191037307, 0.5096347290849914 ],   [ 0.5172941999844842 ] ] [ [ 0.531292644737, 0.3354644096344466, 0.5153411264323275 ],   [
>   0.5172940554705523 ] ]

Where the first three are the inputs and the bold ones the corresponding output.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the network trained?

Comment: No the model is not trained. I will use fitness to train the model. The network with the highest fitness will be used in the generation. I use mutation and crossover. However, the activation function's output should change when input changes right?

Comment: If the network isn't changed then the outputs will be very similar. If you're using a genetic algorithm you should create a pool that has a lot of varying weights, and randomly backpropagate them a few times so the output does change a lot with different input. I have a library for genetical algorithms on synaptic, take a look: https://github.com/wagenaartje/gynaptic

Comment: Great, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

The activation function computes `f(Theta*x + b)`. Now the most likely case is that `Theta` is somehow 0 or close to 0 and that's why you only see the bias.

You should print out the initial weights of the network.